# Concept maps. What exactly they are?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, terminology

I would like you to recommend me a definitive book about concept maps. I've been taking a look to a wide variety but none of them seemed clear to me.

Comment: Could you mention books that you have not found helpful so far, so that people might identify things that you haven't seen yet?

Comment: Also, what is a cognitive map and in what context are you examining them?

Comment: Concept mapping as I understand it, is a way to elicit the thought process of a person (or people) in a pseudo-scientific manner. You might want to modify this question to put in a reasonable definition of a concept map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_map) :

> A concept map or conceptual diagram is a diagram that depicts
>   suggested relationships between concepts. It is a graphical tool that
>   designers, engineers, technical writers, and others use to organize
>   and structure knowledge.
>
> A concept map typically represents ideas and information as boxes or
>   circles, which it connects with labeled arrows in a downward-branching
>   hierarchical structure. The relationship between concepts can be
>   articulated in linking phrases such as *causes, requires, or
>   contributes to*.

The technique was first developed in 1970's by [Joseph D. Novak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_D._Novak). You can try one of his books e.g. [Learning, Creating, and Using Knowledge: Concept Maps as Facilitative Tools in Schools and Corporations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415991854)